# new Date() behaves differently in different environment, why?

Tags: javascript, node.js, date

when I define the same date in chrome, it shows the expected result.
but when I run it in node.js, the code is below:

```js
var date = new Date(2015, 1, 1);
console.log(date); // it displays: 2015-01-31T16:00:00.000Z
```

My question is **why not 2015-02-01**?

Comment: are you in a GMT+0800 timezone?

Comment: It's not `new Date()` that is behaving differently, it's the implicit conversion to string that is being formatted differently (and in the case of Node.js, is not compliant with ECMA-262).

Comment: Can you share the answer please ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

***It's timezone issue.*** In Chrome, printed date and time is adjusted by your local timezone information. But date in Node.js you printed, its string format is ISO String with no adjustment timezone value.

So, both `new Date(2015, 1, 1)` have the same value in Chrome and Node.js.

Try `console.log(date.toLocaleDateString())`. You would get 2015-2-1.

Comment: It's more a date formatting issue than a timezone issue. *toLocaleDateString* may also return inconsistent results on different platforms (e.g. different browsers). For me, `new Date(2015, 1, 1).toLocaleDateString()` returns 01/02/2015 in Safari and Chrome, and 02/01/2015 in Firefox.

Comment: @RobG You have same result In both case which demonstrate Feb. 1. But cases in question are different. One is Jan. 31 and the other one is Feb. 1.

Answer (score 0):

You're just printing the date object

```
var date = new Date(2015, 1, 1)
console.log(date);
```

For more in-depth explanation check:

https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_date_formats.asp

Also, if your goal is having this format **`2015-02-01`** check https://momentjs.com/. For your case:

(Using moment.js)

```
moment(new Date(2015, 1, 1)).format('YYYY-MM-DD') // "2015-02-01"
```